# How to update multiple rows of a database table in ASP.NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-update

I want to update multiple rows in ASP.NET Core, but I get an error:

> InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'EntityQueryable' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.

This is my code:

```
var data = _db.UserTable.Where(a => a.CityIDn == selectedid);

foreach (var items in data)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    items.CityID = 2;
                });

    _db.Update(data);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for multiple rows:

```
var data = _db.UserTable.Where(a => a.CityIDn == selectedid).ToList();

foreach (var item in data)
{
    item.CityID = 2;
    _db.UserTable.Update(item);
}
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

And for one record, try like this:

```
var data = _db.UserTable.Where(a => a.CityIDn == selectedid).FirstOrDefault();
if(data != null)
{
    data.CityID = 2;
    _db.UserTable.Update(data );
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of Update should be `items`, it worked for me, you can have a try.

```
var data = _db.UserTable.Where(a => a.CityIDn == selectedid).ToList();
foreach (var items in data)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    items.CityID = 2;
                });

    _db.Update(items);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: i try this but its not work without any error when i debug it in last "}" debuger stop on it

Comment: savechange is null. no in first foreach loop was broken and screen gona white

Comment: Try to remove `await Task.Run` and change `CityID` directly. Make a breakpoint on `_db.Update(items);` to make sure `items` have been modified. If you still have problems, try to use `UserTable` instead of `_db` : `_db.UserTable.Update(items);`@mirad100 ssa

Answer (score 0):

Now available in [EF Core 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew), you can do [Bulk Updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates):

```
await _db.UserTable.Where(a => a.CityIDn == selectedid).ExecuteUpdateAsync(
    s => s.SetProperty(b => b.CityID, b => 2));
```